# Recommendations on buying a rigged horse model

Tags: texturing, rigging, export, import

I need to purchase a semi-realistic horse model that I can pose. My intent is to composite still renders of it into several photos. I also need to re-texture it and would prefer a model that comes with an editable map. I have been out of the 3D loop since 2012 when I was in school and I could use some advice on the best sites and artists to shop from. I've seen several models priced under 50 dollars that seem like they'd work, but there are so many to choose from and it's tough to know which ones are the best value. I'm willing to accept some deformation in the horse's body if it keeps the cost under $50. I'll be happy if the model can pass for a Creature Shop version of realistic, like Falcor (Neverending Story) or a Tauntaun from Star Wars. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for purchasing recommendations. (Point 7 on the [off topic list](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/2217).)